# Simple alternative to reversible jump for nested models?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, reversible-jump

Suppose that we have a model such that $p(y\mid k, \theta_1,\dots,\theta_{k_\text{max}})$ depends only on $k,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_k$. Hence, as $k$ assumes the values $1,\dots,k_\text{max}$, we have a family of nested models. With suitable priors for $k$ and the $\theta_j$'s, instead of using Green's reversible jump scheme, I was thinking if an iteration of the following much simpler procedure could work:

1. Sample $k$ from the (available) full conditional distribution $k\mid y,\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{k_\text{max}}$.
2. Do a Metropolis-Hastings step, sampling *en bloc* only $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_k$.
3. Repeat.

Is this already used in the literature? If not, what is the catch? Does it sample the space of nested models incorrectly or inefficiently?

Comment: Hi Zen! Unfortunately, you cannot do Gibbs proper in this setting as the measures over different parameter spaces are mutually exclusive. This is why reversible jump is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative to reversible jump is to go for the respective posterior probabilities of the different models,
$$\mathbb P(\mathfrak M_k|\mathbf x)\propto
\pi(\mathfrak M_k) \underbrace{\int_{\Theta_k} \pi_k(\theta_k)f_k(\mathbf x|\theta_k)\,\text d\theta_k}_\text{$\mathfrak e_k$: evidence on $\mathfrak M_k$}$$
which can be approximated from simulations of $\pi_k(\theta_k|\mathbf x)$. Hence a marginal MCMC scheme could proceed by exploring the set of models (or model indices) as follows:

At iteration $t$, with current model index $k^{(t)}$

1. make a proposal $k^\prime\sim q(\cdot|k^{(t)})$
2. compute an unbiased estimator $\hat{\mathfrak e}_{k^\prime}$, e.g. by running some MCMC simulations targetting $\pi_{k^\prime}(\cdot|\mathbf x)$
3. accept the move with probability $$\dfrac{\pi(\mathfrak M_{k^\prime})\hat{\mathfrak e}_{k^\prime}}{\pi(\mathfrak M_{k^{(t)}})\hat{\mathfrak e}_{k^{(t)}}}\,\dfrac{q(k^{(t)}|k^\prime)}{q(k^\prime|k^{(t)})}$$

In general, it is not possible to use solely simulations from the encompassing (or largest) model, since the posterior measures on the $\theta_k$'s are supported by sets of measure zero wrt the encompassing measure. This is why, even if model $\mathfrak M_k$ corresponds to a subset of $(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_{k_\text{max}}$ it must be treated as a completely different object, with a separate prior density.

Comment: Xi'an: thank you for you insightful answer!

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-28/issue-1/Bayesian-analysis-of-mixture-models-with-an-unknown-number-of/10.1214/aos/1016120364.full) *Bayesian analysis of mixture models with an unknown number of components—an alternative to reversible jump methods* by Matthew Stephens is somewhat along those lines

> However, our approach appears the more natural and elegant in this
> context, exploiting the natural nested structure of the models and
> exchangeability of the mixture components. As a result we remove the
> need for calculation of a complicated Jacobian, reducing the potential
> for making algebraic errors

It's a bit more complicated than your setting -- the full conditional for $k$ isn't available so $k$ is modified by a birth-death process

Comment: Tks for the reference, Thomas.